# How to access an association in view from one POCO with several references to another

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Sorry about the title; couldn't think of a better one.

Any way, I'm accessing an associated property in my view like so:

```
@Model.Company.CompanyName // No problems here...
```

The model is a viewmodel mapped to an EF POCO. The Model has several properties associated to the Company table. Only one of the properties in the model share the same name as the PK in the Company table. All the other properties reference the same table:

```
public class MyModelClass 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public int AnotherCompanyId { get; set; } // References CompanyId
    public int AndAnotherCompanyId { get; set; } // References CompanyId

    public Company Company { get; set; }
 }

 public class Company
 { 
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
 }
```

I'm obviously missing something here.

How can I get the names of the other companies in my Model?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The model is a viewmodel mapped to an EF POCO

I think you are confusing the notion of a view model. A view model is a class that is specifically designed to meet the requirements of your view. So if in your view you need to display the company name and not the company id then your view model should directly contain a `CompanyName` property. Or a reference to another view model (`CompanyViewModel`) which contains the name directly. It is then the responsibility of your controller action to query your domain models (EF entities) and aggregate them into a single view model tat will contain all the necessary information that the view requires.

Here's how a typical view model might look like:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public CompanyViewModel Company { get; set; }
    public CompanyViewModel AnotherCompany { get; set; }
    public CompanyViewModel AndAnotherCompany { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Where the data comes from in this view model is not important. You could have the Company property populated from  your EF stuff, the AnotherCompany property populated from a XML file and AndAnotherCompany from WCF.

Comment: I believe understand the view-model concept. I'm mapping my POCOs from my data layer to the view-model in the controller using automapper to avoid using my POCOs directly for the view..facilitate testing, etc. If I understand correctly you are saying I should add a `AnotherName` property to my view-model and in the controller assign the value correct?

Comment: The view model should contain all the properties that the view requires.

Comment: This was a misplaced question; was really more of an Entity Framework issue for me (which I resolved). In the context of this question, you are absolutely correct. Thanks for taking a look!